# How to clear smarty templates_c folder using php code

Tags: smarty

I have an issue in smarty cache. When an update content from admin website I am able to view the new content immediately but when i check the same page in main site i see the old content instead of new content.When i clear the templates_c dir in server and refresh the main site,I see the new content at the first attempt.I believe somewhere it has the problem with caching.Please give me a solution for this asap.Thank you.

Comment: In addition to my problem,I need a know a way to clear templates_c folder using php code.I had google and tried it never seemed to work.So i need some experts advice

Comment: how about clearCache() http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.clear.cache.tpl and clearAllCache() http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.clear.all.cache.tpl ?

Comment: In addition, be sure that compile_check is enabled (its enabled by default) http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl

Comment: Hi,I tried $smarty->clearAllCache(); but the page become blank while load

Comment: The below source  i get when i use $smarty->clearAllCache(); and $compile_check = TRUE;<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
%

Comment: Thank you buddy.$smarty->clear_all_cache();worked for me.Since I do use smarty 2.1. Thanks anyway for helping out

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do (I haven't tested it myself):

```
<?php
$path = 'path/to/templates_c';
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        unlink($fileinfo->getPath());
    }
}
?>
```

By the way, be **very** cautious when dealing with unlink(), you may accidentally delete files you didn't mean to